# Schedule that runs every day at a specific time with hh:mm:ss

Tags: java, date, kotlin

I'm trying to run code at a specific time every day, but with hh:mm:ss. I'm specifically, trying to run it at 5PM EST every day, so Timezones needs to be accounted for.

Here's my attempt, in kotlin:

```
val timer = Timer()
val format = SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss") 
val date = format.parse("11:07:09")
timer.schedule(object : TimerTask() {
    override fun run() {
       // code here
    }
}, date)
```

I wasn't able to get that working, and even if I did, I'm not sure how I'd add timezones to it as well.

How can I do this?

Comment: Tip: `EST` is not a [real time zone name](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). Perhaps you mean something like `America/New_York`.

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Also no matter if you use one or the other, beware that format pattern strings are case sensitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
java.util.Date
.from(
    ZonedDateTime.of( 
        LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" )  ) , 
        LocalTime.parse( "11:07:09" ) , 
        ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) 
    )
    .toInstant()
)
```

## Details

A `java.util.Date` represents a date with a time-of-day in UTC.

You have ignored the date and the zone/offset.

Your result is apparently defaulting to 11 AM on January 1, 1970.

## java.time

Also, the terrible `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` classes were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes.

Represent your target time-of-day.

```
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse( "11:07:09" ) ;
```

Get current date, today’s date. Requires a time zone. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

Put these together to determine a moment.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( today , lt , z ) ;  // Time-of-day will be adjusted if not valid on that date in that zone.
```

Adjust into UTC. Same moment, same point on the timeline, different wall-clock time.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;  // Adjust from zone to UTC.
```

Avoid the legacy date-time classes. But if you must interoperable, you can convert back and forth by calling new methods added to the old classes.

```
java.util.Date d = java.util.Date.from( instant ) ;
```

You will likely want to improve this code to see if your desired moment has already passed. To compare, use `isAfter` and `isBefore` methods.

## Executors

The `Timer` class has been supplanted by the executor framework. Search the Oracle Java Tutorials and Stack Overflow to learn more.

With an executor, you can schedule a task to run at a certain moment. But you do so indirectly, by specifying a waiting period rather than a time-of-day. The scheduling executor takes an argument for an initial delay. You can calculate that delay as a span of time between the current moment and the desired moment.

To calculate that span of the time, use the `Duration` class.

```
Duration d = Duration.between( Instant.now() , instant ) ;
```

Keep in mind that you *cannot* expect split-second perfect timing of your tasks to be executed. The scheduling of your JVM on the host OS, and of your Java threads within the JVM, can involve delays.

Of course, you will also need to record a history of your tasks when completed. When your app does a shutdown, then relaunch, it needs to study the history to figure out how to set up a new schedule. This issue is beyond the scope of this Answer. Read up on writing files, using a database, or relying on some other [persistence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_(computer_science)) scheme.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for the well written information Basil! One question, does this check, let's say, every second until it's time? So, I can just  write this in my code, and I don't need a Runnable schedule that checks every second to make this work?

Comment: @kinx I added a bit more info. But you need to do some study. Read the Oracle tutorial, search Stack Overflow, and search the internet.